# Rashi’s Explanation Doesn’t Seem to Fit in the Dibbur Hamatchil

Tags: rashi, parashat-ki-tisa

[Rashi on Shemot 32:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.18?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) explains קול ענות גבורה and קול ענות חלושה however the dibbur hamatchil is אין קול ענות גבורה.  Why is he explaining the קול ענות חלושה here when the dibbur hamatchil indicates that he only should be concerned with the קול ענות גבורה?  Why wouldn’t he explain קול ענות חלושה in a separate dibbur hamatchil?

Comment: Must’ve slipped by his editor!

Answer (score 1):

It is very common for Rashi to explain the continuation of a passage after he quotes the first few words. So, respectfully, I do not think this is a legitimate question.

See for example Rashi to Koheles 10:1

> זְבוּבֵי מָוֶת יַבְאִישׁ יַבִּיעַ וְגוֹ'. כְּגוֹן בִּימֵי הַחֹרֶף, שֶׁאֵין בִּזְבוּבִין כֹּחַ, וְהֵם קְרוֹבִים לָמוּת, גַּם אִם בָּא לְתוֹךְ שֶׁמֶן רוֹקֵחַ וּמִתְעָרֵב בִּבְשָׂמִים, הוּא מַבְאִישׁוֹ, וְהוּא מַעֲלֶה קֶצֶף, שֶׁקּוֹרִין אשקו"א בְלַעַ"ז, וְנִרְאֶה בוֹ כְמִין אֲבַעְבּוּעוֹת, וְזֶהוּ מַשְׁמָעוֹ שֶׁל "יַבִּיעַ". הֲרֵי דָבָר קַל שֶׁהִפְסִיד דָּבָר חָשׁוּב. כַּךְ, יָקָר מֵחָכְמָה וּמִכָּבוֹד הַסִּכְלוּת מְעָט, שֶׁהֲרֵי הִכְרִיעַ אֶת כֻּלָּם. הֲרֵי שֶׁהָיָה אָדָם זֶה שָׁקוּל בְּמֶחֱצָה עֲבֵרוֹת וּמֶחֱצָה זְכֻיּוֹת, וּבָא וְעָבַר עֲבֵרָה אַחַת וְהִכְרִיעַתּוּ לְכַף חוֹבָה, נִמְצֵאת סִכְלוּת זֶה שֶׁהוּא דָבָר מֻעָט, יָקָר וְשָׁקוּל וְכָבֵד יוֹתֵר מִכָּל הַחָכְמָה וְהַכָּבוֹד שֶׁהָיָה בוֹ, שֶׁהֲרֵי הִכְרִיעַ אֶת כֻּלָּם:
>
> Dead flies decay and pollute, etc. E.g., in the winter season, flies have no strength, and are near death; nevertheless, if it falls into a perfumer’s oil and becomes mingled with the perfumes, it causes it to become putrid and it assumes a foam, which is called escume in O.F., and a sort of bubbles appears in it, and this is the meaning of ‘יַבִּיעַ.’ So an insignificant thing1 spoiled a precious thing.2 So does a little foolishness outweigh wisdom and honor, for it outweighed them all. Suppose that a man was equally divided with transgressions and merits, and he came and committed one transgression, which tipped the scale [causing him] to be guilty. The result is that this foolishness which is small, is heavy and weighs, and is heavier than all the wisdom and honor that he possessed, for behold, it outweighed them all.

[From Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.10.1?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Ecclesiastes.10.1.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) See also Rashi to[Koheles 3:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.3.11?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Ecclesiastes.3.11&lang2=bi).

In fact, it is also common for Rashi to explain two verses in one dibbur hamaschil. Here are two Pesukim from Megillas Rus [Ch. 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth.1.16-17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): 16

> וַתֹּ֤אמֶר רוּת֙ אַל־תִּפְגְּעִי־בִ֔י לְעָזְבֵ֖ךְ לָשׁ֣וּב מֵאַחֲרָ֑יִךְ כִּ֠י אֶל־אֲשֶׁ֨ר תֵּלְכִ֜י אֵלֵ֗ךְ וּבַאֲשֶׁ֤ר תָּלִ֙ינִי֙ אָלִ֔ין עַמֵּ֣ךְ עַמִּ֔י וֵאלֹהַ֖יִךְ אֱלֹהָֽי׃
>
> But Ruth replied, “Do not urge me to leave you, to turn back and not follow you. For wherever you go, I will go; wherever you lodge, I will lodge; your people shall be my people, and your God my God.

17

> בַּאֲשֶׁ֤ר תָּמ֙וּתִי֙ אָמ֔וּת וְשָׁ֖ם אֶקָּבֵ֑ר כֹּה֩ יַעֲשֶׂ֨ה יְהוָ֥ה לִי֙ וְכֹ֣ה יֹסִ֔יף כִּ֣י הַמָּ֔וֶת יַפְרִ֖יד בֵּינִ֥י וּבֵינֵֽךְ׃
>
> Where you die, I will die, and there I will be buried. Thus and more may the LORD do to me if anything but death parts me from you.”

Rashi to verse 16 explains both verses in one shot:

> כִּי אֶל אֲשֶׁר תֵּלְכִי אֵלֵךְ. מִכַּאן אָמְרוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ זִכְרוֹנָם לִבְרָכָה, גֵּר שֶׁבָּא לְהִתְגַּיֵּר מוֹדִיעִין לוֹ מִקְצַת עֳנָשִׁים, שֶׁאִם בָּא לַחֲזֹר בּוֹ יַחֲזֹר, שֶׁמִּתּוֹךְ דְּבָרֶיהָ שֶׁל רוּת אַתָּה לָמֵד מַה שֶּׁאָמְרָה לָהּ נָעֳמִי. "אָסוּר לָנוּ לָצֵאת חוּץ לַתְּחוּם בַּשַּׁבָּת". אָמְרָה לָהּ, "בַּאֲשֶׁר תֵּלְכִי אֵלֵךְ". "אָסוּר לָנוּ לְהִתְיַחֵד נְקֵבָה עִם זָכָר שֶׁאֵינוֹ אִישָׁהּ". אָמְרָה לָהּ, "בַּאֲשֶׁר תָּלִינִי אָלִין". "עַמֵּנוּ מֻבְדָּלִים מִשְּׁאָר עַמִּים בְּתַרְיַ"ג מִצְוֹת", "עַמֵּךְ עַמִּי". "אָסוּר לָנוּ עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים, "אֱלֹהַיִךְ אֱלֹהָי". "אַרְבַּע מִיתוֹת נִמְסְרוּ לְבֵית דִּין, "בַּאֲשֶׁר תָּמוּתִי אָמוּת". "שְׁנֵי קְבָרִים נִמְסְרוּ לְבֵית דִּין, אֶחָד לְנִסְקָלִין וְנִשְׂרָפִין וְאֶחָד לְנֶהֱרָגִין וְנֶחְנָקִין". אָמְרָה לָהּ, "וְשָׁם אֶקָּבֵר":
>
> **For wherever you go, I shall go.** From here our Rabbis of blessed memory derived that if a [prospective] proselyte comes to convert, we inform him of some of the punishments [for violating the commandments] so that is he decides to renege [from his intention to convert], he can renege; for out of the words of Rus, you can learn what Naomi said to her. [Naomi said.] “We may not venture outside the boundary [of 2000 cubits beyond city limits] on Shabbos.” She [Rus] replied to her, “For wherever you go I shall go.” [Naomi then said,] “We are prohibited to allow a woman to be secluded with a man who is not her husband.” She [Rus] replied, “Where you lodge, I will lodge.” [Naomi said,] “Our nation is separated from other nations by 613 commandments,” [and Rus replied,] “Your people are my people.” [Naomi said,] “Idolatry is forbidden to us,” [to which Rus replied,] “Your God is my God.” [Naomi then said,] “Four [types of] death penalties were delegated to Beis Din [to punish transgressors],” [and Rus replied,] “Where you die, I will die.” [Naomi continued,] “Two burial plots were delegated to Beis Din [to bury those executed], one for those stoned and those burned, and one for those decapitated and those strangled.” She [Rus] replied, “And there I shall be buried.

This is very common. In fact, I found all three examples by flipping randomly through my mikraos gedolos to the chamesh megillos. As you learn more, you will find more too. Happy hunting!

Comment: Would it be possible to please bolster this assertion with relevant examples so I can see how they relate to my question?

Comment: I edited my response to include examples. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

If you look at an Artscroll/chumash in the pasuk itself there are 3 קול ענות.

Quoting the arsctoll rashi page 454 point one "the spelling ענות appears three times in our verse, but the vowelization changes. The first two times the word ענות is spelled with a chataf patach under the ע and without a dagesh in the נ. The third time, it's spelled with a patch under the  ע and with a dagesh in the נ. both words come from the root of ענה." the word ענה is not like most sheroshim and changes with a single trup to change it's meaning. the thing that is bothering rashi is that why this little trup change. then from reading rashi one would figure it out